# Regex match every string inside double quotes and include escaped quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, string-matching

There are quite a few similar questions already but none of them works in my case. I have a string that contains multiple substrings inside double quotes and these substrings can contain escaped double quotes.

For example for the string **'And then, "this is some sample text with quotes and \"escaped quotes\" inside". Not that we need more, but... "here is \"another\" one". Just in case.'**, the expected result is an array with two elements;

- `"this is some sample text with quotes and \"escaped quotes\" inside"`
- `"here is \"another\" one"`

The `/"(?:\\"|[^"])*"/g` regex works as expected on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/awsjEi/1); however, when I use `String#match()` the result is different. Check out the snippet below:

```js
let str = 'And then, "this is some sample text with quotes and \"escaped quotes\" inside". Not that we need more, but... "here is \"another\" one". Just in case.'
let regex = /"(?:\\"|[^"])*"/g

console.log(str.match(regex))
```

Instead of two matches, I got four, and the text inside the escaped quotes is not even included.

[MDN mentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value) that if the `g` flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups will not. If I want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, I need to use `RegExp.exec()`. I've tried it, the result is the same:

```js
let str = 'And then, "this is some sample text with quotes and \"escaped quotes\" inside". Not that we need more, but... "here is \"another\" one". Just in case.'
let regex = /"(?:\\"|[^"])*"/g
let temp
let matches = []

while (temp = regex.exec(str))
  matches.push(temp[0])

console.log(matches)
```

How could I get an array with those two matched elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is a more optimal regex without `|` operator:

```js
const str = String.raw`And then, "this is some sample text with quotes and \"escaped quotes\" inside". Not that we need more, but... "here is \"another\" one". Just in case.`
const regex = /"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"/g
console.log(str.match(regex))
```

Using `String.raw`, there is no need escaping quotes twice.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/YIrKn0/1). Btw, [28 steps](https://regex101.com/r/YIrKn0/3/) vs. [267 steps](https://regex101.com/r/YIrKn0/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"\\]*                  any character except: '"', '\\' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"\\]*                  any character except: '"', '\\' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why regex doesn't work as expected is because a single backslash is an escape character. You'll need escape the backslashes in the text:

```js
let str = 'And then, "this is some sample text with quotes and \"escaped quotes\" inside". Not that we need more, but... "here is \"another\" one". Just in case.';
let regex = /"(?:\\"|[^"])*"/g

console.log(str);
console.log(str.match(regex))

str = 'And then, "this is some sample text with quotes and \\"escaped quotes\\" inside". Not that we need more, but... "here is \\"another\\" one". Just in case.';

console.log(str);
console.log(str.match(regex))
```

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't think about escaping the backslashes.