# Regular expression to match a substring in a quoted string

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will match a substring within a quoted string and will not match it outside of the quoted string. For example, if the substring is `my substring` then in the following example it should match the second entry and unmatch the first and last entry:

```
This entry of my substring is unmatched. "This entry of \"my substring\" is matched." This entry of my substring is unmatched.
```

Conversely, in the next example, the expression should match the first and last entry and unmatch the second entry:

```
"This entry of my substring is matched." This entry of my substring is unmatched. "This entry of my substring is matched."
```

It should also work for the case where the quoted string containing the target substring is surrounded by other quoted strings:

```
"A quoted string." "This entry of my substring is matched." "A quoted string."
```

Comment: In your second example there is no double quote ending the last quoted string.  Is that intensional?

Comment: `(?<!\\)".*?(my substring).*?(?:(?<!\\)"|$)` seems to work The match is the quoted string and `my substring` is in the first captured group. https://regex101.com/r/kFKNTk/1  It doesn't work if there is a quoted string before the quoted string that contains `my substring`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, thank you for your comment, it's not perfect because of the scenario you mentioned, but might be useful in some circumstances.
I added the case with the preceding quoted string to my question, and I added a quote where it was missing (thanks to your comment).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, what is the purpose of the question mark in the `.*?` fragment that appears twice in your pattern?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568137/regex-match-every-string-inside-double-quotes-and-include-escaped-quotation-mark

Comment: @jvisprime `.*` will match as much as it can regardless of what those characters are.  o if your string was `A quote (") delimits this string: "some stuff my_substring more stuff" and the rest` then the first quote would be considered the start of the quoted string even though it clearly isn't.  `.*?` will match only as much as necessary which will choose the closes quotes to my_substring.